# Thinking in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm currently busy learning Ruby and Rails, and since I have a background in C-based languages, some concepts of Ruby are new and somewhat alien. Especially challenging for me is adapting to the "Ruby-way" of approaching common problems, hence I often find myself coding C in Ruby, which is not what I'm trying to achieve.

Imagine having a schema like this:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20111119180638) do
    create_table "bikes", :force => true do |t|
        t.string   "Brand"
        t.string   "model"
        t.text     "description"
    end
end
```

The database already contains several different bikes. My goal is to get an array of all brands represented in the database.

Here is my code:

```
class Bike < ActiveRecord::Base
    def Bike.collect_brands
        temp_brands = Bike.find_by_sql("select distinct brand from bikes")
        brands = Array.new
        temp_brands.each do |item|
          brands.push(item.brand)
        end
        brands
    end
end
```

How would a Ruby guru write code to achieve this?

Comment: This would be better asked on http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to that place. I wasn't aware that such thing exist.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

tl;dr: Your entire method can be replaced with `Bike.uniq.pluck(:brand)`.

---

This functionality already exists (see the end of my answer), but first, lets step through your code and make it more idiomatic:

First and foremost, use two spaces per level of indentation, not four, not eight, and *not* tabs. Use *two spaces*. This is not personal preferences, this is an *extremely* strong convention within the Ruby community and pretty much required if you intend to participate.

Next, there almost *never* a good reason to use this pattern in Ruby:

```
 brands = Array.new
 temp_brands.each do |item|
   brands.push(item.brand)
 end
```

When you want to translate one array into another array (really, one Enumerable into another Enumerable) by applying some code to each of values in the input array, use [`map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) or [`collect`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) (which are synonyms):

```
brands = temp_brands.map { |item| item.brand }
```

Next, you can take advantage of [`symbol#to_proc`](http://pragdave.pragprog.com/pragdave/2005/11/symbolto_proc.html) to make the above code a little clearer:

```
brands = temp_brands.map &:brand
```

This will look strange to the uninitiated, but it *is* clearer once you're used to working with `map` and `&:field`. A little bit of experience will make the intent of this line of code very obvious: It's applying the `brand` method to each element in the array, and it's exactly equivalent to the previous `{ |item| item.brand }` version.

Now, your entire method can become a pretty simple one-liner:

```
def Bike.collect_brands
  Bike.find_by_sql("select distinct brand from bikes").map &:brand
end
```

That inline select/distinct SQL is kind of ugly, especially since ActiveRecord already lets us [select specific fields](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#selecting-specific-fields) with `select`, and make the results distinct using `uniq`:

```
def Bike.collect_brands
  Bike.select(:brand).uniq.map &:brand
end
```

As a final iteration we can use [`pluck`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#pluck) instead of `map` to pull only the fields out of the results that we're interested in. But, because `pluck` actually modifies the SQL being generated to only include the fields being plucked, we can omit the `select(:brand)` portion, and our code boils down to an incredibly short single line containing two chained methods:

```
def Bike.collect_brands
  Bike.uniq.pluck(:brand)
end
```

Note that the order is important because `pluck` always returns an array, not an ActiveRecord relation ready for additional method chaining. `Bike.pluck(:brand).uniq` would select the brand from every record (`select brand from bikes`) and then, *in Ruby*, reduce the array to the unique items. Potentially a very expensive operation.

And that's it, `Bike.uniq.pluck(:brand)`. As a C programmer, you'll find that many of repetitive tasks you're used to doing with small loops are practically *already solved for you* by the language itself or by supporting libraries. The amount of code you *don't* write can be very surprising, once you've learned to write idiomatic Ruby and Rails code.

Comment: I almost downvoted as I read the "never ever" sentence, but then upvoted instead :)

Comment: I was still being too verbose. ActiveRecord is smart enough that `.select(:field).uniq.pluck(:field)` and `.uniq.pluck(:field)` are synonyms.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking your time to provide such a detailed answer. I really appreciate that.